# Issues installing synapse launcher

Tags: package-management, 9.10, software-sources, synapse

I am trying to install synapse launcher on my desktop . I am using these two commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synapse
```

However I am getting an error with the second command saying

```
E: Some index files failed to download,
   they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I presume this has something to do with my connection to the hosting servers. But what I don't understand is the fact that synaptic is working it just seems to be something about that ppa. I don't know what I am doing wrong as the commands are widely suggested around the web, But they don't seem to work for me! I would greatly appreciate some advice on this as it is proving to be very frustrating.

Many thanks,
George

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you are using 9.10 and there [don't appear to be any packages](https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ppa/+packages) for 9.10 in the PPA.

You need to either file a bug asking them to provide 9.10 packages, upgrade to 10.04, or build from source, sorry!